# AutocompleteExtender not working in master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete

I have a problem regarding the autocomplete extender in ASP.NET - it works fine in all pages I have, but NOT in a master page and i don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" Width="200px" CssClass="TextBoxClass"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtSearch_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="txtSearch"
    CompletionInterval="0" 
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" 
    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
    CompletionSetCount="10" EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionListOggetti"
    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" UseContextKey="True">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Code behind:

```vb
<System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()> _
Public Shared Function GetCompletionListOggetti(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()
    ' Insert code to return a string array here…
    Return AutoCompleteOggetti(prefixText)
End Function
```

The problem is that `GetCompletionListOggetti` is never called.

I repeat - it works fine on content page! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it by putting the web method (in your case, GetCompletionListOggetti) in the code behind file of the content page instead of master page. And it works only for web method in the same code behind file not in a separate asmx service. For this, don't forget to add *EnablePageMethods="true"* property to your script manager too.

It seems like AutoCompleteExtender's service method is never called when it's defined inside a user(or custom) control's code behind file and a master page is a kind of control indeed.

The downside of this fix is that you have to put the same service method in EVERY contents page which uses this master page. Not very elegant. Another downside is somehow the css of suggestion dropdownlist is not working properly. Still I couldn't figure out the walkaround. Anybody better idea?

Comment: "The downside of this fix is that you have to put the same service method in EVERY contents page which uses this master page." Inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **ServicePath** property of the AutoCompleteExtender to override the default behaviour of calling back to the loading (not master) page.

Add your function to the code-behind of a webservice page (.asmx), a dummy page, or default.aspx etc.

If using a webservice page, you would need to add/uncomment the line:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

for VB, or for C#

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```